# Get number from column which is x digits long

Tags: powerquery

I have the problem that in a column a number (4 digits long) is defined, which is embedded in a string. That means I cannot cut off after a certain length and extract the number. Is there a way to get this number out of the text? If necessary with Regex (if possible)? It can be possible that there are other numbers within the string, but none of them are 4 digits long.

**Example**:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 8904 sit amet 12
Lorem 1234 ipsum 22 dolor sit amet
Lorem ipsum dolor sit 9876 amet
```

**Result**:

```
8904
1234
9876
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

Starting with this 1-column table, named Table1 in Excel:

[image]

Here's the M code I use:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each List.Select(Text.SplitAny(Text.Select([Column1],{"0".."9","a".."z","A".."Z"}),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"),each Text.Length(_) = 4 ){0})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

To get this result:

[image]

Comment: I love this. I've never seen Text.Select before, had to look up what it was doing. Had no idea there was a string sanitizing function like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let
    Source = < Your Data Source >,
    FilterTrimSplit = Table.TransformColumns(Source,
        {{"TextColumn", each
          Text.Split(Text.Trim(Text.Select(_, {" ","0".."9"}))," ")
        }}),
    Select4Digits = Table.TransformColumns(FilterTrimSplit,
        {{"TextColumn", (C) =>
          List.First(List.Select(C, each
              Number.FromText(_) <> null and Text.Length(_) = 4)),
          Int64.Type}})
in
    Select4Digits
```

Let's walk through this with an example. The first step is to strip out everything except spaces and digits. Then trim any whitespace at the beginning or end of the string and convert it to a list by splitting on spaces.

```
Text.Select("Lorem ipsum dolor 8904 sit amet 12", {" ", "0".."9"}) = "   8904   12"
Text.Trim("   8904   12") = "8904   12"
Text.Split("8904   12", " ") = {"8904", null, null, "12"}
```

Now that we have a list let's pick out the elements that are numbers and have four digits. Finally, pick the first element of the list.

```
List.Select({"8904", null, null, "12"},
    each Number.FromText(_) <> null and Text.Length(_) = 4) = {"8904"}
List.First({"8904"}) = "8904"
```

We could use `Number.FromText` again but I specified the column type to be `Int64.Type` instead.

---

Note: You can skip the first `Select` and `Trim` steps if you do error handling on `Number.ToText` with the `try` ... `otherwise` functionality.

```
let
    Source = < Your Data Source >,
    Split = Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"TextColumn", each Text.Split(_," ")}}),
    Select4Digits = Table.TransformColumns(Split,
        {{"TextColumn", (C) =>
            List.First(List.Select(C, each
                (try Number.FromText(_) otherwise null) <> null
                and Text.Length(_) = 4)),
        Int64.Type}})

in
    Select4Digits
```